# disable persistent connections in mariadb for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, mariadb

Is there any way how to disable persistent jdbc:mysql connections to mariadb directly in tomcat/or mariadb server? 
I would like to do it similar way how I did it for php, where I disabled it in PHP (scripts in PHP won't fail, they'll just use non-persistent connections silently).

I have a java servlet which produces many connections which stay in sleep for very long time and causes "too many connection" issue.

As I am not java programmer, I am not able to change java servlet codes. (so I need to do it at higher level if possible)

Answer (score 0):

- Lower the `wait_timeout`.
- Decrease the number of connections in your "connection pool", if you have one.
- Decrease the number of "clients" in your web server is willing to spawn.
- As a last resort, increase MySQL/MariaDB's `max_connections`.

Comment: Thank you Rick! I did 1., 3., 4. already. Can you please give me short info how to make point 2. "connection pool"?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about JDBC's connection pool.